# How to fit entire 2D world map on iPhone screen iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, mapkit

I  want to scale the entire 2D world so that it fits in an iPhone screen in landscape.  As you can see below, the map does not include the US and South America, or the north or south poles.   This is the most zoomed out view I can get.

I want to be able to see the entire earth from north to south, east to west.

It doesn't matter that there may be some white space at the left and right of the screen to fit the entire world in the view.

I have tried all the different map types (.hybrid, .satellite, .satellitehybrid etc ) but no solution.

It makes no difference using UIKit with MKMapView() or SwiftUI with Map(), you get the same results.

Any ideas how to do this ?

Here is my code (using SwiftUI):

```
struct MapExample: View {
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
    center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 25.7617,
        longitude: 80.1918
    ),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(
        latitudeDelta: 90,
        longitudeDelta: 360
    )
)

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

[image: World view zoomed out to full extent]